# underscore JS sort using array element

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have this array. How do I use underscore js '_.sortBy' to sort the country based on using last element i.e. 0 2,1,3,4 :

```
["33001","ALL","0"]["33001","APAC", "2"]["33001","America", "1"]["33001","EMEA", "3"]["33001", "Sland", "4"]
```

Expected result : `["ALL","America","APAC","EMEA","Sland"]`

Could anyone help me out to get this output. Thanks.

Comment: Show some code .. what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You may have an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't *need* to use `_.sortBy`, you can use native JavaScript:

```js
let array = [
  ["33001", "ALL", "0"],
  ["33001", "APAC", "2"],
  ["33001", "America", "1"],
  ["33001", "EMEA", "3"],
  ["33001", "Sland", "4"]
];

console.dir(                        // Log, illustratively
  array.sort((a, b) => a[2] > b[2]) // Apply a custom ordering
       .map(entry => entry[1])      // Return the field you want
);
```

Explanation:

1. Sort the array using [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
2. [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the resulting array to then return (log, in this case) the second value.

However, `array.sort((a, b) => a[2] > b[2])` can be replaced by `_.sortBy(arr, items => items[2])` if you really want to use underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with this array

```
var arr = [["33001","ALL","0"],["33001","APAC", "2"],["33001","America", "1"],["33001","EMEA", "3"],["33001", "Sland", "4"]];
```

The sorting can be done by specifying the function `sortBy` uses to compare your array elements.

`var result = _.sortBy(arr, (items) => { return items[2]; });`

After sorting, you can grab the values you want using `map`

`var finalResult = result.map((items) => { return items[1]; });`

Comment: This can be shortened to `_.sortBy(arr, items => items[2]).map(item => item[1])`, when you only `return` from an arrow function you can omit the `{}` and `return` statement. When only one parameter, it doesn't need to be wrapped in brackets. Chaining also saves on instantiating variables needlessly.

Comment: True, the notation just makes me feel uneasy, like leaving brackets off of an if statement or for loop.  The extra variables were just for clarity so op could see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

You could take the standard methods of Javascript with [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var array = [["33001","ALL","0"], ["33001","APAC", "2"], ["33001","America", "1"], ["33001","EMEA", "3"], ["33001", "Sland", "4"]],
    result = array
        .sort((a, b) => a[2] - b[2])
        .map(a => a[1]);
        
console.log(result);
```